# Splitting a string by commas, and removing some characters

Tags: r, regex, split

Here are the values I would like to separate:

```
f <- data.frame(x = c("c(58663.809, 232648.355, 0)", "c(5902.873, 232674.248, 0)"))
```

I would like to remove the "c(", separate the two values (by the comma), and remove the final two characters "0)".

Two resulting columns should look like this:

```
x = c(58663.809, 5902.873),
y = c(232648.355, 232674.248)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using `dplyr` and `tidyr` libraries.

From the string `x` we remove `"c("` and `")"` characters, use `separate_wider_delim` to divide data in different columns while dropping the last value. Finally, use `type.convert` to change the column values to it's respective types.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

f %>%
  mutate(x = gsub("c\\(|\\)", "", x)) %>%
  separate_wider_delim(x, names = c("x", "y", NA), delim = ", ") %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  data.frame()

#          x        y
#1 58663.809 232648.4
#2  5902.873 232674.2
```

Comment: This works great!  Thanks for all the answers.  I chose this one because I am most familiar with 'dplyr' and 'tidyr'

Answer (score 2):

If those strings are from `dput()`, the function to reverse the process and get an object from text representation is `dget()` (or just `eval(parse())`):

```r
f <- data.frame(x = c("c(58663.809, 232648.355, 0)", "c(5902.873, 232674.248, 0)"))

# dget reads from files or conections
dget_str_xy <- function(str_){
  textConnection(str_) |> 
  dget() |> 
  head(2) |> 
  `names<-`(c("x","y"))
}

f <- 
  dplyr::mutate(f, x = lapply(x, dget_str_xy)) |>
  tidyr::unnest_wider(x)
f
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>        x       y
#>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 58664. 232648.
#> 2  5903. 232674.
dput(f)
#> structure(list(x = c(58663.809, 5902.873), y = c(232648.355, 
#> 232674.248)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
#> -2L))
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `eval` + `str2lang` to parse the numbers in the string

```
setNames(
    data.frame(
        do.call(
            rbind,
            eval(str2lang(sprintf("list(%s)", toString(unlist(f)))))
        )
    )[c(1, 2)],
    c("x", "y")
)
```

which gives

```
          x        y
1 58663.809 232648.4
2  5902.873 232674.2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, using lookarounds in `regexpr` to find characters between "c(" and ", 0)" and extract `regmatches`. Next `strsplit`, `rbind`, and `type.convert` to numeric. Finally convert `as.data.frame` and `setNames`.

```
> f$x |> regexpr(r'{(?<=c\()(.*)(?=,\s0\))}', text=_, perl=TRUE) |> 
+   regmatches(x=f$x) |> strsplit(', ') |> do.call(what='rbind') |> 
+   type.convert(as.is=TRUE) |> as.data.frame() |> setNames(c('x', 'y'))
          x          y
1 58663.809 232648.355
2  5902.873 232674.248
```

- `(?<=c\()` positive lookbehind for `"c("`
- `(.*)` capturing group , matches any character
- `(?=,\s0\))` positive lookahead  for `", 0)"`
- see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gWNpfV/1)

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(f)
structure(list(x = c("c(58663.809, 232648.355, 0)", "c(5902.873, 232674.248, 0)"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

`f <- data.frame(x = c("c(58663.809, 232648.355, 0)", "c(5902.873, 232674.248, 0)"))`

## Define the pattern to remove zero

`pattern <- ",\\s*0"`

## Remove the specified  (i.e zero) pattern from the column 'x'

`f$x <- gsub(pattern, "", f$x)`

## Print the modified data frame

`print(f)`
`x=f[1,]`
`y=f[2,]`
#insert  a coma and a line
`cat("x=",f[1,], ","   ,"\n" ,"y=",f[2,])`

Answer (score -1):

`f <- data.frame(x = c("c(58663.809, 232648.355, 0)", "c(5902.873, 232674.248, 0)"))

pattern <- ",\s*0"

f$x <- gsub(pattern, "", f$x)

print(f)
x=f[1,]
y=f[2,]

cat("x=",f[1,], ","   ,"\n" ,"y=",f[2,])`